# SQL: Select all records when one column value change

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having trouble to find the solution for this SQL Query.

Let me explain You on base of the table below:

```
   Group            DATUM    VALUE
    1002  2017-03-29 12:01:00     0.1
    1002  2017-03-29 12:02:36     0.2
    1002  2017-03-29 12:03:40     0.1
    1002  2017-03-29 12:04:44     0.2
    2523  2017-03-29 12:05:47     0.3
    2523  2017-03-29 12:06:51     0.1
    2523  2017-03-29 12:07:55     0.2
    2523  2017-03-29 12:08:59     0.3
    2523  2017-03-29 12:09:03     0.4
    3002  2017-03-29 12:10:07     0.5
```

I would like to get the data of every group. So on the base of table above the `GROUP: 1002` has changed to `GROUP: 2523`, so i wanna receive **all the records** of `GROUP: 1002`, which is:

```
Group             DATUM    VALUE
1002  2017-03-29 12:01:00     0.1
1002  2017-03-29 12:02:36     0.2
1002  2017-03-29 12:03:40     0.1
1002  2017-03-29 12:04:44     0.2
```

and furtehrmore when the `GROUP: 2523` is finished and the value changed to `GROUP: 3002`, i would get all the records for the `GROUP: 2523` and so on...

**The reason of doing this:**

The raw data has to be read into another programme (KNIME) every time `GROUP` value changes (here is the part of `SQL`), then some specific values need to be calculated for each group, the new table has to be written in database.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you looking for some automatic process which monitors all inserts and reacts when the first new group key is inserted?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I use Oracle

Comment: @Shnugo exactly! I am looking exactly for some automatic process which will monitor all inserts on base of change of the value in `GROUP`

Comment: Really the only way to achieve this is via a trigger on insert or update. Other than that, perhaps think about your infrastructure - https://www.rethinkdb.com/ can push data changes to an endpoint which would allow you to mediate and on send

Comment: @Trent rethinkdb.com looks interesting, however at my company we have quite hard policies and it might take quite lots of time until it will go through. i do need a very quick solution to it. What about connecting to database every 5 minutes and checking if the value of the `GROUP` has changed from the last one, if not: no action, if yes: download all records for the `GROUP`? is it even possible...

Comment: You'll need a trigger, where you read the group key of the last inserted row (`LAG()` or `TOP 1 ... ORDER BY DATUM DESC` or `MAX()`), but you  must be aware, that this might lead to severe issues, if there are parallel inserts or bulk / multi row inserts taking place. You might use some polling action from your application to read with a little time lag...

Comment: I meant exactly this *What about connecting to database every 5 minutes and checking if the value of the GROUP has changed*, when I suggested a *polling*.

Comment: Given you use oracle - perhaps you can use coherence https://blogs.oracle.com/felcey/entry/pushing_realtime_data_changes - this seems to be exactly what you want

Answer (score 1):

You would write a trigger to check whether a new insert has another group than the latest insert. In that case you'd have to call some routine that pushes the data to where you want it. Something like this:

```
create or replace trigger trg_latest_group_to_knime
before insert on mytable
for each row
declare
  v_last_group integer;
begin
  select max("GROUP") keep (dense_rank last order by datum)
  into v_group
  from mytable;

  if :new.group <> v_last_group then
    push_records_to_knime_for_group(v_last_group);
  end if;
end trg_latest_group_to_knime;
```

Comment: that sounds fair enough! need to try it out